# Does the react day picker have time selection?

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

Does this Widget have the capability to select a date with a timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so, there is this though: https://github.com/react-component/time-picker

Answer (score 0):

You can try the material-ui React-DateTime-Picker It Works like charm.

Reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-datetimepicker